# Now AsyncTask and asyncTaskLoader is deprecated then how come I run in background thread?

Tags: java, android

is there any new method to run in background like asynctask ?
**Will WorkManager solve this problem in java?** or
how to run in background thread in java ?
Now I need to request data in server by using background thread

Answer (score 0):

I use `Thread` for this purpose.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        
        // Background
        
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            // On Post Execute
            
        }}); }}).start();
```

You can also use lambda if your project supports it.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    // Background

    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        // On Post Execute     
        
    });
}).start();
```

Comment: Ok bro just give me a link to read it,I can also use it in java right? because I'm creating an app in java

Comment: You RxJava if working inJava. Coroutines if working in Kotlin

Comment: @MadhanMohan checkout the link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread)

Comment: Thanks bro Now asynctaskloader is deprecated for that what can i use?

Comment: @MadhanMohan According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader), you can use the support library's [AsyncTaskLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

Comment: Thanks bro,Both are same right just they changed android to androidx jetpack ?

Comment: @MadhanMohan You are welcome! Yes, `androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader` is in the androidx jetpack.